# I got puzzled paradoxically in a discombobulated discombobulation

Tags: word-choice

One of the speakers in our office meeting used this line today and everybody in the hall literally "**got puzzled paradoxically in a discombobulated discombobulation**" and *panicked* for a while thinking he was speaking in tongues... At the end, some praised him for his good use of the dictionary, i guess, but some argued that it was ***Chihuahua*** English... Now, is that genuinely a correct combination of words or exaggerated use of dictionary? as far as the "English language and usage" is concerned. Formally and informally

**Edit:** When analyzed, it sounds like saying, **I was *confused* *confusedly* in a *confused* *confusion***... is that good English or tautology?

Comment: You will have to define "genuinely correct combination". Nothing at all prevents [colorless green ideas from sleeping furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).

Comment: I wish you were present and heard how it sounded for yourself... (like thunders)... these are just what I could quickly write down, he said like a tone more of really heavy words... We are all well educated but we can't communicate like this..

Comment: Try replacing the words with their shorter-simpler synonyms and tell me what happened.

Comment: Assigning him to work in a windowless office filing invoices from 1993 until he has calmed down should work wonders.

Comment: @Erick Kowal Perfect comment... If we all walked in streets with pocket dictionaries to impress each other with heavy _tautological_ statements or vocabularies, instead of looking somewhat intelligent, we will waste alot of time and look Crappy..

Comment: The episode in question sounds ripe for a musical cartoon parody on YouTube. Imagine it going viral in your company...

Comment: Yah... I'am driving to the Mall, just to possess a pocket Oxford, cz i have my Presentation tomorrow... I swear to revenge... The guy is gonna be there, and i swear, he will not understand a word coming from my mouth... (can't wait to **spifflicate** some brains tomorrow)... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not grammatically incorrect. I'd hazard a guess that it was intended as emphatic tautology. Whether it achieved the speaker's desired effect, I'll leave for you to judge.

Comment: Yes indeed, he "achieved his _utmost_ desired effect" when we all got _puzzled paradoxically in a discombobulated discombobulation_ of words.